# Adding span to a particular text in an menu item

Tags: menus, css, sub-menu

Read many posts regarding this but all are for all menu items.

Issue is: I want to wrap some text in menu item. I tried adding HTML to menu but that does not work because of Walker_Nav_Menu class which is already added and the menu item is filter by the_title. So that does not work.

I want submenu item like this if some item has text sale,like Summer Sale so sale should be in red. So I want to add span to this menu item text.

is it possible to add text to menu items like this?

Answer (score 0):

I just added span and it worked very well

[image]

Check result

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works with the normal wp_nav_menu. Thats why I mentioned I am using Walker_Nav_Menu class. This is removing the html from the menu level